# $(this).children() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code:

```
<tr><td class="style3">test</td></tr>
```

and

```
$("tr").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).css("background-color","#d9e8cd");
    $(this).css("font-weight","bold");
    $(this).children().css("color","#222222 !important");
  }, 
  function () {
    $(this).css("background-color","");
    $(this).css("font-weight","");
    $(this).children().css("color","#4b4a4a");
  }
);
```

The problem is that the text colour will not change, i tried specifying the tr but it wont work so I assumed targeting the td would make it work because of the style3 class which specifies a colour.

How can I make it so that the colour of the text changes when the tr is hovered over?

**This is an online demo** http://jsfiddle.net/B7dMd/

Comment: Could you reproduce the issue on http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: Why don't you do `find('td')` instead of `children()`?

Comment: [This JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c8Kgp/) shows that it does work.  Part of the problem may be that #222222 and #4b4a4a are not that visually different on the color spectrum.  Also note that you cannot use `!important` when you are using `.css()`

Comment: @Jared Farrish: what would it change? (and after looking at the code - `children()` perhaps will be "faster" ;-)

Comment: I tested you code and it works...
[link](http://jsfiddle.net/ePkEv/) . Did you include JQuery ?

Comment: Is your code set to run once the DOM hierarchy has been constructed, i.e. wrapped with `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`?

Comment: You don't need ` !important` there is nothing more important than directly assigned style property.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko: Actually, that's not true: http://jsbin.com/eramab/1/edit People frequently *think* it's true, but it isn't. A sufficiently-specific stylesheet rule with `!important` can override an inline style. But if you add `!important` to the `style` ([like this](http://jsbin.com/eramab/4/edit)), that wins.

Comment: It is simply works: http://jsfiddle.net/B7dMd/1/

Comment: @Jared Farrish: nope, but why would you prefer `find('td')`? `children()` isn't less semantic or readable

Comment: @JaredFarrish: `find` traverses all children within, including children of children. While `children` only returns the first-level children which is all that is needed. As per [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/find/) `The .find() and .children() methods are similar, except that the latter only travels a single level down the DOM tree.` So `find` would be incorrect to use if you only care about the first-level children. Performance is irrelevant at this point.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl - Thank you for the redundant tutorial. Back to the rainbows.

Comment: @JaredFarrish: You asked `Why don't you do find('td') instead of children()?`. I tried to answer that for you. No need to be rude and unprofessional about it!

Comment: @FrançoisWahl - I appreciate that you took the time to spell all of that out. It was an off-hand, half-distracted comment while I was trying to put a fiddle together. So. Sure. Thanks. zerkms fixated on it, as he does sometimes, and I just played along. Nobody seems to point out the obvious "enhancement", just my goofy comment. Phfft.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The important syntax is not supported by jQuery CSS. if you really need to add "!important" you might want to try CSS DOM cssText:

```
$(this).children().css('cssText', 'color:#222222 !important');
```

To point it out - in most of the cases, there is no reason why you should add an !important in inline styling, because inline styles have a high priority, you'll only have to do it to override another !important rule.

Comment: That's not correct. Non-inline styles with `!important` will override inline styles (unless the inline styles have `!important` as well).

Answer (score 0):

When you add a `tr` which isn't inside a `table` the browser interprets it without table tags (`td` and `tr`) and let only the text. You can see this behavior if you inspect the element [here](http://jsfiddle.net/NtE8N/).

To fix the issue add it inside a table.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="style3">test</td>
    </tr>
<table>
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NtE8N/1/)